# How to get data from one wordpress site to another

Tags: widgets, links

I have the following sites:
1.  Community News site
2.  Classifieds site
3.  Coupon Site

Is there any way I can get data from my classifieds and coupon site on my community news site....like in the form of a widget (latest posts)
Thank you for any guidance you can give.
Anna

Answer (score 0):

I think the simpelest solution would be to use the generated RSS-Feeds and integrate them somehow with an RSS Widget Plugin. A plugin search could help you here, I guess.

Comment: addition to @websupporter: you can code with [`fetch_feed()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) to get a site's feed into your format. :)